# How can I POST data from javascript to a c sharp back-end, and then receive it back?

Tags: javascript, c#, api, web

So, I am fairly new to C Sharp and I can't figure out how I can basically submit a POST request via javascript (in the front-end) using fetch, send it to a C Sharp back-end to process the data, and then receive it back to my site.

My final goal is to achieve a search engine, where I can get user input from javascript and send it to my C Sharp back-end so I can crawl sites from a database and return the ones which contain the highest volume of the key-word.

Here is what I am currently working within the front-end:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
    <title>Search Engine</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="search">
        <h2>Search Engine</h2>
        <input name="search" type='text' placeholder='Search' />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        const endpoint = "file to send data to";
        const formEl = document.querySelector('form');
        formEl.addEventListener('submit', async(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const formData = new FormData(formEl);
            const formDataSerialized = Object.fromEntries(formData);

            try {
                const response = await fetch(url, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify(formDataSerialized),
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                });
                const json = await response.json();
                console.log(json);
            } catch(e) {
                console.error(e);
                alert('there was an error!');
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I have a basic form that submits a user search, however, the endpoint in my javascript function is currently empty, since I am not sending the data anywhere.

I was looking around for a long while for a solution where I can make a web server with C Sharp and accept the data that way, however didn't find anything which I can use.
Can anyone please help? I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Yes using ASP.NET, I've tried making a Web Handler which accepts data when it is sent to the file, however I couldn't figure out how to do it after trying a few solutions and decided to ask.

Comment: `trying a few solutions and decided to ask`  - You should add these attempts to the question though

Comment: Unfortunately the example I tried has nothing to do with my problem specifically, however was testing a similar system. It was a mailing app that submitted data from front-end inputs and sent it to the back-end to be processed in a "ProcessRequest" function via a Web Handler to send back a message to say that it was received. However, the request keep giving back a "500" error. I can add the app to my question in a separate section if it helps with the solution.